# Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Task'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need your help regarding an error im getting which i have mentioned on the subject,I have amethod which is :

```
           public  Task GetMidRateInEuro(string currencypair)
            {

                using (var db = this.dbContextFactory.Create())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //result is decimal
                        var midrate = db.Fxrates.Where(s => s.CurrencyPair == currencypair).Select(r => r.MidRate).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (midrate != null)
                        
                            return Task.FromResult(midrate);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(false);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        this.logger.Log(currencypair + "midrate" + ex.Message, true);
                        throw ex;
                    }

                }
            }
```

i need to call it in another method ,i just write the part i get this error ,if you need i will share that as well bu im sure it wont help:

```
        var midrate = GetMidRateInEuro("EUR" + currency);  

            //here is where i get error Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Task'                 
            var amountInEurto = accumulatedAmount * (1 /  midrate);
```

im using .NetCore 5,any help will be appreciated

Comment: `public  Task GetMidRateInEuro(string currencypair)`. It returns a `Task`. Either change the return type, or `await` the `Task`.

Comment: @DanielMann may i ask if i add async how should i return?because task.from.result wont work

Comment: GetMidRateInEuro is not async, then why do you return a Task? Just change the return type to decimal, and `return midrate;`

Comment: @KlausGütterand what if the result is null,since the return type is decimal what should i return then?and thanks for your answer

Comment: You could return `decimal?` (aka `Nullable<decimal>`) if you want to allow the method to return a null

Comment: Or, you could make it async (by calling and awaiting `FirstOrDefaultAsync` instead of `FirstOrDefault`) and return the task (awaiting it in the caller)

Comment: @Flydog57 if you mean returning the Task from the FODA call, you'll run into problems if you elide that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you probably wanted more like:

```
public async Task<decimal> GetMidRateInEuroAsync(string currencypair)
{
    using var db = this.dbContextFactory.Create();

    try
    {
        //result is decimal?
        var midrate = (await db.Fxrates.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.CurrencyPair == currencypair))?.MidRate;

        if (midrate.HasValue)
            return midrate.Value;

        //or whatever kind of not-exists handling you want
        throw CurrencyPairDoesNotExistException(currencypair);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.Log(currencypair + "midrate" + ex.Message, true);
        throw; 
    }
}
```

And

```
var midrate = await GetMidRateInEuroAsync("EUR" + currency);  

//here is where i get error Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Task'                 
var amountInEurto = accumulatedAmount * (1 /  midrate);
```

Note, you'll neeed to make this calling method `async` too.. But what return type you give it depends on what it returns. If it's `void` make it `Task`. If it's Something, make it `Task<Something>`

Comment: thanks a milion ,can i ask when we should use only Task and when should use Task<datatype>?

Comment: Simplistically, `void -> Task`, `SomeType -> Task<SomeType>`